# Вывести ошибки полей Angular

Tags: angularjs

Сейчас использую такое условие для кнопки в HTML:

```
ng-submit="appointment.$valid && AppointmentSubmit()"
```

Но форма не отправляется методом `AppointmentSubmit()`. Как я могу просмотреть, что в `appointment.$valid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На кнопку отправки нужно добавить `ng-click="submit()"`.
В контроллере нужно создать метод

```
  $scope.submit= function () {
            //здесь в объекте $error будут доступны ошибки заполнения формы
            if ($scope.appointment.$error) {...}};
```

А `$scope.appointment.$valid` вернёт только true или false.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы работаете в браузере Chrome, то можете установить расширение [Angular Scope Inspector](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angular-scope-inspector/aaglpchhlnofjbbpopfdfgllfkhnljnl) . С его помощью легко можно просмотреть все переменные в scope приложения. После установки, в инструментах разработчика (F12), во вкладке Elements, выбираете в DOM-модели элемент, в котором объявлено angular-приложение (ng-app) и справа смотрите вкладку Scope Inspector